# Flask API & nginx alongside each other

Tags: nginx, flask, ubuntu-20.04

I have a server that I'm trying to set up. I have a Flask server that needs to run on api.domain.com, while I have other subdomains pointing to the server. I have one problem. 2/3 subdomains have no problem using nginx. Meanwhile, my script tries to bind to port 80 on the same machine, therefore failing. Is there a way I can bind my Flask REST script to port 80 ONLY for the subdomain 'api'?
My current config is:

```
server {
        server_name api.domain.me;
        location / {
            error_page 404 /404.html;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5050/;
            proxy_cache off;
            proxy_read_timeout 240s;
    }
}
```

There's a little problem though, nginx likes to turn all POST requests into GET requests, any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found out after a bit of diagnosis.

```
server {
    if ($host = api.domain.me) {
        return 301 https://$host
    }
    # managed by Certbot
```

had to become:

```
server {
    if ($host = api.domain.me) {
        return 497 '{"code":"497", "text": "The client has made a HTTP request to a port listening for HTTPS requests"}';
    }
```

Because Certbot tries to upgrade the request to https but the HTTP method gets changed to GET because of the 301 response code.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way binding two different applications on port 80 at the same time.

I would set up your api like this:

Bind your Flask API to Port `8080`.
On NGINX you can configure you subdomain pointing to your Flask Application

```
upstream flask_app {
  server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}


sever {
  listen 80;
  server_name api.domain.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://flask_app/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
  }
}
```

Comment: There's a little problem though, nginx likes to turn all POST requests into GET requests, any ideas?

Comment: That is not the normal behavior. POST request will be forwarded as POST request to your backend and will never automatically changed to GET request by NGINX. Is there anything in between your browser, NGINX and the Flask App? What is your configuration?

Comment: I've updated my config and it's in the question above.